# Removing referenced entity. Solution, tactics etc

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, spring-data

I'm wondering how to solve problem of removing a record from db, that is in relationship with other record. Here's an exemple. Those are two class that represents User and Comment.

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Getter @Setter
    private long id;

    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private User commentAuthor;

    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
    private Article associatedArticle;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;


    @Getter @Setter
    @Type(type="text")
    private String commentText;

    public Comment(User author, String text){
        this.commentAuthor = author;
        this.commentText = text;
        this.date = new Date();
    }
}
```

And user class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Getter @Setter
    private String username;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String password;

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    private String email;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String role;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date registerDate;

    public User(String username, String password, String email){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
        this.email = email;
        this.registerDate = new Date();
        this.role = "USER";
}

public User(){};
```

As you can see I store information which user added comment. But let's imagine that I want to delete this user. I won't be able to do that if he added comments because I will get SQL error about foreign key etc. I'm pretty sure that it's just bad db design but I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Obviously when deleting user I want to keep his comments and instead of his username just show some info like "User deleted". What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set  field of comments that is linked to user table to null when user is deleted using syntax like ON DELETE SET NULL. Also you need to allow null for that field